# Only center of UIButton is clickable

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkannotationview

I'm adding a custom UIButton to an MKAnnotationView (the "pin" on the map, not the "bubble"), but when I do only the center of the button is clickable.

Here's the method for my button:

```
- (UIButton *)button: (NSString*)text{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [[button titleLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Here I add it to the MKAnnotationView:

```
buildingBtn = [self button:annotations.title];    
[self addSubview:buildingBtn];
buildingBtn.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame of your `UIButton` is probably bigger than that of the `MKAnnotationView`. If that's the case, the button will not receive any touches with locations outside of the annotation view's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

*(Reposted answer material from the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

A solution has been found thanks to @Muncken.

The MKAnnotationView's frame was not set. By setting it myself I control the clickable size. I also found out that it doesn't make sense adding a UIButton to MKAnnotationView, since MKAnnotationView acts as a button.